# Is imgur having problems?

Tags: support, images

Are you experimenting problems viewing and uploading images imgur this days?

I want to know if it is a local thing with me or we are all having issues.

Comment: Imgur are still having issues, we are contacting them to see what's going on (given that the AWS issue has since been resolved).

Comment: Been wondering this for days...

Comment: Yes. Rejecting uploads 1 out of 5-7 times - change file name.. retry and it works (sometimes). Actually came here looking to see if it was mentioned.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes.  The Amazon Web Services is experiencing issues and Imgur uses their server which translates to SE experiencing image rendering and uploading issues.

Reference:

> Unfortunately Imgur is affected by the current AWS server issue.

[image]

Twitter [Link](https://twitter.com/i/web/status/836645670954008576) with another link on the full story.

Meta Question: [Intermittent Failed to upload image; imgur is rejecting the request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/291609/intermittent-failed-to-upload-image-imgur-is-rejecting-the-request)